# jquery preventdefault on submit form will not be re submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I got issue on my code. I Have a html form where the button submit when clicked but there will be some checking first, if all values are true the form will be submitted - but on my code, it didn't work. does anyone have an idea about this?

```js
$("#button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr("at") == "1") { //some checking
    alert("Subsssmitted");
    $("form").submit(function() {
      alert("Submitted"); // it didn't passed the form didn't submitted
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <!-- some code -->
  <button id="button" at="1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: form has no action and method how can you check?

Comment: did you include jquery library ?

Comment: yes, I did include jquery library..

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
$('#form').submit()
```

after

```
$("form").submit(function(){
   alert("Submitted"); // it didn't passed the form didn't submitted
});
```

Since you are just defining event handler but not triggering submit event.

If possible move

```
$("form").submit(function(){
   alert("Submitted"); // it didn't passed the form didn't submitted
});
```

Outside the click event handler

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in that way:

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).attr("at") == "1"){ //some checking
        alert("Subsssmitted");
        // here you trigger event
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
// here you listen event
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    alert("submitted")
})
```

Just get it here https://jsfiddle.net/6hzt663q/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){
// do your validation success 
if(!success){
    event.preventDefault();
}
console.log('fsdfsdfds');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="/google">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <button id="button" at="1" type="submit">Submit"></button>
</form>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me, remove `e.preventDefault()` and try,

```js
$("#button").click(function(e){
  if($(this).attr("at") == "1"){
     $("form").submit(function(){
        console.log('done');
     });
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <button id="button" at="1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed "e.preventDefault();" on button click event and it will work fine.