# How do I create a loading wheel in jQuery that hides itself when a background process in Python is completed?

Tags: python, html, jquery, flask

I am trying to make a loading wheel that displays while a background process is running and hides itself on completion of that background process. The background process is the ingestion process, which runs a web scraper across a Wikipedia page and converts it to a text file, and then ingests it into an LLM model. I want the loading gif to appear the whole time ingestion is running, and then disappear upon completion. I am using Flask to communicate between my front end and back end.

I have tried ajaxComplete on the POST request which only displays the wheel for a millisecond, and the current method which is posted in my code below.

html:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style> #loading { display: none; } </style>
<div class="card-footer">
            <form id="ingestArea" class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="html" name="url" placeholder="Type your message..." autocomplete="off" class="form-control type_msg" required/>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="submit" id="feed" class="input-group-text send_btn"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div id="loading"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/36/3c/2e/363c2ec45f7668e82807a0c053d1e1d0.gif"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var interval;
                $("#messageArea").on("submit", function(event) {
                    const date = new Date();
                    const hour = date.getHours();
                    const minute = date.getMinutes();
                    const str_time = hour+":"+minute;
                    var rawText = $("#text").val();

                    var userHtml = '<div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4"><div class="msg_cotainer_send">' + rawText + '<span class="msg_time_send">'+ str_time + '</span></div><div class="img_cont_msg"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/d5b84Xw/Untitled-design.png" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg"></div></div>';
                    
                    $("#text").val("");
                    $("#messageFormeight").append(userHtml);

                    $.ajax({
                        data: {
                            msg: rawText,   
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/get",
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        var botHtml = '<div class="d-flex justify-content-start mb-4"><div class="img_cont_msg"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/fSNP7Rz/icons8-chatgpt-512.png" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg"></div><div class="msg_cotainer">' + data + '<span class="msg_time">' + str_time + '</span></div></div>';
                        $("#messageFormeight").append($.parseHTML(botHtml));
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
                $("#ingestArea").on("submit",function(event) {
                    var rawText = $("#html").val();
                    $('#loading').show();
                    interval = setInterval(checkStatus, 1000);
                    $("#html").val("");
                    $.ajax({
                        data:{
                            url: rawText,
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/ingest",
                    });
                });
            });
            function checkStatus() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/check_status',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === "in_progress") {
                            $('#loading').show();
                        } else{
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            $('#loading').hide();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                });
        </script>
```

python (using Flask):

```
is_ingesting = False

@app.route('/check_status', methods=['GET'])
def check_status():
    global is_ingesting
    if is_ingesting:
        return jsonify(status="in_progress")
    else:
        return jsonify(status="completed")


def ingest():
    global is_ingesting
    is_ingesting = True
    start_url = request.form["url"]
    scrape_web(start_url, 0)
    if does_vectorstore_exist(persist_directory):
        # Update and store locally vectorstore
        print(f"Appending to existing vectorstore at {persist_directory}")
        db = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings, client_settings=CHROMA_SETTINGS)
        collection = db.get()
        texts = process_documents([metadata['source'] for metadata in collection['metadatas']])
        print(f"Creating embeddings. May take some minutes...")
        db.add_documents(texts)
    else:
        # Create and store locally vectorstore
        print("Creating new vectorstore")
        texts = process_documents()
        print(f"Creating embeddings. May take some minutes...")
        db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory,
                                   client_settings=CHROMA_SETTINGS)
    db.persist()
    db = None
    is_ingesting = False
    print(f"Ingestion complete! You can now run privateGPT.py to query your documents")
    return jsonify("All done!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery preventdefault on submit form will not be re submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881087/jquery-preventdefault-on-submit-form-will-not-be-re-submitted)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the reload on the click of the submit button which is in a form so the element gets shown and instant hidden by css on the reload.

Maybe use the [jquery click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event to don't get your page reloaded on the click.

Comment: So essentially, I can delete $('#loading').show(); within the if statement of check_status() and it will function? Just to clarify?

Comment: Can you please specify your question i don't get it.

Comment: If I delete the line $('#loading').show(); in success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === "in_progress") {
                            $('#loading').show(); it will work?

Comment: If it's shown every time the page loads and only is hidden when the call is successful or failed this should do the trick yea.

Comment: Hey! It seems to not work. the data the user enters appears in the URL but isn't sent to the back end for processing. The loading bar is not shown either.

Comment: did you remove the <style> #loading { display: none; } </style>?

Comment: If you remove all of the javascript code the spinner has to be shown otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I want the loading symbol to be hidden when the initial page is loaded, and then appear when the user submits a URL to the back end for processing. I think I forgot to include the submit area in the code above. I then want it to disappear when the processing in the back end is complete.

Comment: I've updated the html code to reflect this.

Comment: Are you in need of the submit? In my opinion you can just do a button click and the page won't reload. I think that's the overall problem you are showing it and then the reload happens and it gets hidden by css because the submit did reload the page. Otherwise i will look deeper into it. The part with the form was a significant information missing.

Comment: What do you mean by a button click? I think you're probably right about the reload though. And my bad about the form. Sorry! I appreciate the help.

Comment: I mean you can also use this jquery event: https://api.jquery.com/click/ I edited my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above comment is correct! It was a refresh issue. I learned about the preventDefault() method as well! It seems to be an equally correct solution. Here is the following edited code for comparison to my previous code!

```
$("#ingestArea").on("submit",function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var rawText = $("#html").val();
                    $("#html").val("");
                    $.ajax({
                        data:{
                            url: rawText,
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/ingest",
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#loading').show();
                        },
                        complete: function(data) {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                        },
                    });
```

Here's the edited jQuery. I left the style as hidden at the top. This seems to work just great! I deleted the unnecessary python code for the function that tracked progress.